# Newbie - How can I configure a URL alias with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, internal-dns

I really don't know the precise terms for what I want, so I'll give you an example.

I have a Amazon RDS service with an endpoint of:
mydbinstance.someotherstring.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

I have an Ubuntu server. And what I would like is to be able to use amazonrds in my programs to connect to it.

So, I want amazonrds to point to mydbinstance.someotherstring.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a local DNS server.

create a CNAME to your amazon domain.

most parts of this are trivial. The tricky bit is the "zone"

I would make the fake zone "myfakezone.com" and add that as a DNS search / suffix in the is. Add amazonrds.myfakezone.com as the cname.

that assumes your application relies on the os for dns / does DNS in a compatible way.

Comment: Ultimately the application should probably be refactored to support this as a sort of configuration option and not rely on hacking in fake DNS / redirects.

Comment: Damn, it sounds complicated... I thought it would be as simple as adding an entry in a config file like adding an entry in the hosts file. Thanks anyway, I'll think of another way.

Comment: Assuming the IP of the amazon url does not change, you can add the IP / short address combo to the hosts file.